# Why do i get "Must provide query string" on fetch API but not on cURL or Postman?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, fetch-api

I am trying to use the [graphbrainz library](https://github.com/exogen/graphbrainz) on a React app with fetch API, but however I format my request body, this error shows:

> BadRequestError: Must provide query string.    at graphqlMiddleware (C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\node_modules\express-graphql\index.js:76:44)    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

The call is being made like this:

```
let myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

const raw = "{ \"query\": \"{ lookup { releaseGroup(mbid: \\\"99599db8-0e36-4a93-b0e8-350e9d7502a9\\\") { title } }}\"}";

const requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow',
  mode: 'no-cors'
};

fetch("http://localhost:3000", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

I have tried making the same call on Postman and cURL and it works successfully.

The graphbrainz instance is being run as a standalone node server.

Can anyone guide me how to proceed with this or what am I doing wrong? I have exhausted almost all stackoverflow questions and GitHub threads. I have the idea that it must be the bodyParser on the express-graphql server that it is causing this, but I can't see how to change/modify it since it comes from the package I am using.

Comment: check dev tools network request body - test it at some online json validator

Comment: @xadm I used https://jsonlint.com/ and it seems like the JSON is valid. This is really perplexing to me since on postman and cURL works.

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql/examples/4-simple-ways-to-call-a-graphql-api/ ... start using `gql` tag ... use variables https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Comment: @xadm I guess i have to set up an apollo client then to check it out. Will try your suggestions and update. Much appreciated!

Comment: @xadm By using apollo client for react with the useQuery hook it seems to work. Please write it as an answer if you want so i can approve it as the valid answer. Thanks alot

Comment: not a real answer ;) ... check network request, compare to earlier one (fetch, body+headers) ? find the difference?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be escaping inner quotes in the query incorrectly. Try replacing `\"99599db8-0e36-4a93-b0e8-350e9d7502a9\"` with `\\\"99599db8-0e36-4a93-b0e8-350e9d7502a9\\\"`.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work with this change. I still get the same error. I tried escaping all the other inner quotes like you suggested as well but still to no avail.

Comment: I think this is happening because of CORS - without a CORS preflight request you cannot set `content-type` to `application/json`, so it silently remains 'text/plain'. To work around this, set the `GRAPHBRAINZ_CORS_ORIGIN` environment variable to `*` before starting graphbrainz and remove `mode: "no-cors"` from your request.

Comment: I had set GRAPHBRAINZ_CORS_ORIGIN in an .env file since yesterday because I had blatant CORS errors and after setting the variable it was all good but the error kept persisting somehow? Anyway, i am using the @apollo/client library now as xadm suggested and it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to stringify your body payload before sending it.

```js
const raw = JSON.stringify({
  "query": "{ lookup { releaseGroup(mbid: \"99599db8-0e36-4a93-b0e8-350e9d7502a9\") { title } }}"
});
```

doing this will stringify your payload to

```
"{\"query\":\"{ lookup { releaseGroup(mbid: \\\"99599db8-0e36-4a93-b0e8-350e9d7502a9\\\") { title } }}\"}"
```

Comment: I thought my version of the body payload was already stringified like that. But nevertheless, even with stringification like you suggested, i get the same error...

Comment: Well do you have app.use(bodyParser.json());  in the node js ? We need this to get the payload.

Comment: That's a good point. In the node server I'm not sure if the bodyParser is in there, since i am simply using the graphbrainz library as an out of the box server as instructed on their documentation... On their GitHub page it seems there is no bodyParser as far as i can see: [their index.js file](https://github.com/exogen/graphbrainz/blob/master/src/index.js). But still i get the feeling it should work though